# Merge on meta: [tags] and [tagging]

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

In making some other tag synonym requests, I've discovered that Bicycles.Meta.SE has a tag called [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and one called [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging). Are these substantively different? Presumably both cover what tags to use.

Comment: Note that if you're going to refer to meta tags, the tag syntax is [meta-tag: {tagname}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), "tagging" is a synonym of "tags."  I suggest that we follow suit because there is no apparent value in being inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a suggested synonom in place for this since 2017.

```
tags × 15   ->> tagging × 24    freiheit    Mar 28, 2017
```

I've just approved it.

```
Merge results
updating post history, 15 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 15 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 12 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'tags': [tags] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 36
tag remapping of [tagging] and [tags] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```